# Wordpress Multisite with primary CSS and Functions file

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I am running a wordpress multisite server with more than 15 domains.

What I would like to do is manage the style.css and functions.php for all for all of the domains from one file for all domains (1 style.css 1 functions.php) because a majority of the styles and functions are the same across all of my domains, however I would like the option to add domain specific options in each child theme.

Can this be done or would it be a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

We actually do something similar. What I've done is created a PHP file in the `/mu-plugins/` directory. PHP files in there will load regardless of active theme or plugins.

You can read up on <kbd>[Must Use Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins)</kbd> in the Codex. They work just like a plugin but are always loaded and can't be activated/deactivated.

So if you create `/wp-content/mu-plugins/lahree.php` and `/wp-content/mu-plugins/lahree.css`, you'll be able to treat the `.php` file like a global `functions.php` of sorts (since it's always loaded). From there you can enqueue the `.css` file to effectively use it as a network-wide/global `style.css` file.

Inside the functions in the `lahree.php` file you can compare the current blog name, site url, or even active theme to load specific stylesheets or run certain functions just on those specific sites.

You can see in the <kbd>[Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/)</kbd> that the `mu-plugins` files are loaded incredibly early, so you may need to adjust the priority of `add_action` hooks if you're planning on overwriting styles loaded in the theme.

**lahree.php** would look something like this:

```
<?php
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wlnb_wp_enqueue_scripts' );
    function wlnb_wp_enqueue_scripts(){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'lahree-global', WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR. '/lahree.css' );

        if( site_url() == 'SPECIFIC_SITE_URL_1' )
            wp_enqueue_style( 'lahree-site-1', WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR. '/lahree-1.css' );

        if( site_url() == 'SPECIFIC_SITE_URL_2' )
            wp_enqueue_style( 'lahree-site-2', WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR. '/lahree-2.css' );      
    }

    add_action( 'wp_head', 'do_something' );
    function do_something(){
        if( site_url() == 'SPECIFIC_SITE_URL_3')
            echo 'This is the Third Site';

        if( site_url() == 'SPECIFIC_SITE_URL_4')
            echo 'This is the Fourth Site';
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just so I understand what you are saying:

1 - I add the code you suggest to /mu-plugins/... and it will supercede my theme(s) css and functions files(?)

2 - how can I also 'enqueue' my child theme's css and function file's at a lower priority or to also be read?

Or did I misunderstand what you explained?

Comment: Your parent theme functions/css will be loaded, and the your child theme's will be loaded after that. These ones will be loaded before. Instead of modifying the child theme priority, you can modify the priority of your "global" CSS files by lowering the priority, for example: `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lahree-global-assets', 20 );`. The PHP files shouldn't be "overwriting" each pther per se so you shouldn't have to worry about that